# LDA with gensim - strange values for perplexity

Tags: lda

We're running LDA using gensim and we're getting some strange results for perplexity. We're finding that perplexity (and topic diff) both increase as the number of topics increases - we were expecting it to decline. We've tried lots of different number of topics 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,50,100. We've also played around with alpha (symmetric and auto) and keep getting the same results.

Our documents have 20+ words but most of them are 20-30. Are these documents too small for LDA to work?

Should we try to increase the amount of training data (we are running on 100k)? Or increase number of passes (but it looks like it has converged)?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Somewhere I remember seeing that you should normalize the perplexity by diving it by the number of topics. Curious if you tried that.